# HTML/CSS Nested Dropdowns

Tags: html, css, button, dropdown

My problem is that the second level of dropdowns don't want to work. It is always displaying the <kbd>**Random Stuff 3.x**</kbd> buttons. Any idea on how to get this working? I feel like the problem lies in the `.dropdown-content:hover > .dropdown-content` line.

I do not want a solution that uses lists/links/bootstrap, I need a solution with buttons and divs

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <button>Random Stuff</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button>Random Stuff 1 ></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <button>Random Stuff 1.1</button>
      <button>Random Stuff 1.2</button>
      <button>Random Stuff 1.3</button>
    </div>
    <button>Random Stuff 2</button>
    <button>Random Stuff 3 ></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <button>Random Stuff 3.1</button>
      <button>Random Stuff 3.2</button>
      <button>Random Stuff 3.3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Joonas honestly man, the stack overflow system is designed a bit stupidly. If you don't get the answer in like 24h then no one ever sees your question again. So the only way to have your question answered is to ask it again. I hate doing this but there is a definite problem in the system when it comes to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167400/room-for-joonas-and-frank).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
    display: inline-block; // Helping showing own when hover.
}

// Key area
button:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display:block; 
}
```

Comment: This works nicely except for two things. The 3rd dropdown is not aligned correctly (I removed the top: 0 but still it is off a bit) and secondly you can't press the last dropdown buttons. The dropdowns disappear when you move your mouse over them. Please help :) Here is a fiddle of the problems https://jsfiddle.net/rma0wwnu/

Comment: You missed the "top: 0;". However you right but then need the change current structure I tried to cover with current html structure - https://jsfiddle.net/rma0wwnu/3/